# Tag Link do React Router Dom não funciona

Tags: react, react-router

Estou iniciando no reactjs e estou fazendo um blog em react seguindo um tutorial. A rota funciona quando escrevo na URL a rota que eu quero visualizar. O problema é quando clico em algum item do menu (component NavBar.jsx) e nada acontece.

Quero que quando clicar em um item do menu exiba a página correspondente.

Nas minhas pesquisas não encontrei solução porque todas as rotas ficam no App.js entre o componente NavBar e o Footer.

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3"
```

App.js

```js
import NavBar from "./components/navbar/NavBar";
import Footer from "./components/footer/Footer";

import Home from "./pages/home/Home";
import Login from "./pages/login/Login";
import Register from "./pages/register/Register";
import Settings from "./pages/settings/Settings";
import Single from "./pages/single/Single";
import Write from "./pages/write/Write";
import About from "./pages/about/About";
import Contact from "./pages/contact/Contact";

import { BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch, 
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <NavBar />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}> 
              <Home /> 
            </Route>
            <Route path="/login"  component={Login} exact> <Login /></Route>
            <Route path="/register" component={Register} exact> <Register /></Route>
            <Route path="/settings" component={Settings} exact> <Settings /></Route>
            <Route path="/post/:postId" component={Single} exact> <Single /></Route>
            <Route path="/write" component={Write} exact> <Write /> /></Route>
            <Route path="/about" component={About }exact> <About /></Route>
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} exact> <Contact /></Route>
          </Switch>
      <Footer />
    </Router> 
  );
}

export default App;
```

NavBar.jsx

```js
import "./navbar.css";
import imgBanner from "../../full-banner.jpg";
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function NavBar() {
    return (
<div className="bannerFull">
  <img src={imgBanner} />
  <nav>
      <ul className="listItems">
          <li className="topItem">
            <Link className="link" to="/" >Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li className="topItem"><Link className="link" to="/about" >Sobre</Link></li>
          <li className="topItem"><Link className="link" to="/contact" >Contato</Link></li>
          <li className="topItem"><Link className="link" to="/write" >Postar</Link></li>
          <li className="topItem"><Link className="link" to="/register" >Registrar</Link></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
  <h1>Blog ReactJS</h1>                                                                                             
</div>                                                                                              
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Só consegui fazer a tag Link funcionar tirando o menu do NavBar.jsx e colocando no App.js. Então, inseri a tag nav com ul e li em App.js junto com as rotas.

NavBar.jsx

```
export default function NavBar() {

return (
    <div className="bannerFull">
        <img src={imgBanner} />
    
        <h1>Blog ReactJS</h1>                                                                                               
    </div>                                                                                              
)
```

}

App.js

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch, 
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {

  return (
    <Router>
        <div className="TopNavBar">
          <nav>
            <ul className="listItems">
              <li className="topItem">
                <Link className="link" to="/" >Home</Link>
              </li>
              <li className="topItem"><Link className="link" to="/about" >Sobre</Link></li>
              <li className="topItem"><Link className="link" to="/contact" >Contato</Link></li>
              <li className="topItem"><Link className="link" to="/write" >Postar</Link></li>
              <li className="topItem"><Link className="link" to="/register" >Registrar</Link></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <NavBar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home}> 
            <Home /> 
          </Route>
          <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} > <Login /></Route>
          <Route path="/register" exact component={Register} > <Register /></Route>
          <Route path="/settings" exact component={Settings} > <Settings /></Route>
          <Route path="/post/:postId" exact component={Single} > <Single /></Route>
          <Route path="/write" exact component={Write} > <Write /> /></Route>
          <Route path="/about" exact component={About} > <About /></Route>
          <Route path="/contact" exact component={Contact} > <Contact /></Route>
        </Switch>
      <Footer />
    </Router> 
  );
}
```